# Adding columns pandas series, based on conditional time series

Tags: python, pandas

I have pulled some data from the internet which is basically 2 columns of hourly data for a whole year:

```
france.GetData(base_scenario, utils.enumerate_periods(start,end,'H','CET'))
```

output

```
2015-12-31 23:00:00+00:00    23.86
2016-01-01 00:00:00+00:00    22.39
2016-01-01 01:00:00+00:00    20.59
2016-01-01 02:00:00+00:00    16.81
2016-01-01 03:00:00+00:00    17.41
2016-01-01 04:00:00+00:00    17.02
2016-01-01 05:00:00+00:00    15.86...
```

I want to add two more columns basically 'peak' hour and an 'off peak' hour scaler columns. So if the times of the day are between 0800 and 1800 there will be a 1 in the peak column and if outside these hours there will be a 1 in the off peak column.

Could anyone please explain how to do this.

Many thanks

Comment: do you know how to extract the hours of the __datetime__ object? You can compare the column to a fixed number, like `df['col']>= 8`. A new column can be appended just by assigning a new name, like `df["new_col"]=df["old_col"]`. Essentially, that's all there is to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) if not `DatetimeIndex`, then use [`between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) to column `peak` and tested for [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) - if `NaN` get `False` and if some value get `True`. Then boolean values are converted to `int` (`False` -> `0` and `True` -> `1`) by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) and last from column `peak` get `peak-off` (thanks [Quickbeam2k1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122903/adding-columns-pandas-series-based-on-conditional-time-series#comment69449672_41123034)):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': {'2016-01-01 01:00:00+00:00': 20.59, '2016-01-01 07:00:00+00:00': 15.86, '2016-01-01 10:00:00+00:00': 15.86, '2016-01-01 09:00:00+00:00': 15.86, '2016-01-01 02:00:00+00:00': 16.81, '2016-01-01 03:00:00+00:00': 17.41, '2016-01-01 05:00:00+00:00': 15.86, '2016-01-01 04:00:00+00:00': 17.02, '2016-01-01 08:00:00+00:00': 15.86, '2015-12-31 23:00:00+00:00': 23.86, '2016-01-01 18:00:00+00:00': 15.86, '2016-01-01 06:00:00+00:00': 15.86, '2016-01-01 00:00:00+00:00': 22.39}})
print (df)
                             col
2015-12-31 23:00:00+00:00  23.86
2016-01-01 00:00:00+00:00  22.39
2016-01-01 01:00:00+00:00  20.59
2016-01-01 02:00:00+00:00  16.81
2016-01-01 03:00:00+00:00  17.41
2016-01-01 04:00:00+00:00  17.02
2016-01-01 05:00:00+00:00  15.86
2016-01-01 06:00:00+00:00  15.86
2016-01-01 07:00:00+00:00  15.86
2016-01-01 08:00:00+00:00  15.86
2016-01-01 09:00:00+00:00  15.86
2016-01-01 10:00:00+00:00  15.86
2016-01-01 18:00:00+00:00  15.86
```

```
print (df.index)
Index(['2015-12-31 23:00:00+00:00', '2016-01-01 00:00:00+00:00',
       '2016-01-01 01:00:00+00:00', '2016-01-01 02:00:00+00:00',
       '2016-01-01 03:00:00+00:00', '2016-01-01 04:00:00+00:00',
       '2016-01-01 05:00:00+00:00', '2016-01-01 06:00:00+00:00',
       '2016-01-01 07:00:00+00:00', '2016-01-01 08:00:00+00:00',
       '2016-01-01 09:00:00+00:00', '2016-01-01 10:00:00+00:00',
       '2016-01-01 18:00:00+00:00'],
      dtype='object')

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index) 

print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2015-12-31 23:00:00', '2016-01-01 00:00:00',
               '2016-01-01 01:00:00', '2016-01-01 02:00:00',
               '2016-01-01 03:00:00', '2016-01-01 04:00:00',
               '2016-01-01 05:00:00', '2016-01-01 06:00:00',
               '2016-01-01 07:00:00', '2016-01-01 08:00:00',
               '2016-01-01 09:00:00', '2016-01-01 10:00:00',
               '2016-01-01 18:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

```
df['peak'] = df.between_time('08:00', '18:00')
df['peak'] = df['peak'].notnull().astype(int)
df['peak-off'] = -df['peak'] + 1
print (df)
                       col  peak  peak-off
2015-12-31 23:00:00  23.86     0         1
2016-01-01 00:00:00  22.39     0         1
2016-01-01 01:00:00  20.59     0         1
2016-01-01 02:00:00  16.81     0         1
2016-01-01 03:00:00  17.41     0         1
2016-01-01 04:00:00  17.02     0         1
2016-01-01 05:00:00  15.86     0         1
2016-01-01 06:00:00  15.86     0         1
2016-01-01 07:00:00  15.86     0         1
2016-01-01 08:00:00  15.86     1         0
2016-01-01 09:00:00  15.86     1         0
2016-01-01 10:00:00  15.86     1         0
2016-01-01 18:00:00  15.86     1         0
```

Another solution is if first get `boolean` mask by conditions and then convert it to `int`, for inverting mask use `~`:

```
h1 = pd.datetime.strptime('08:00:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()
h2 = pd.datetime.strptime('18:00:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()
times = df.index.time
mask = (times >= h1) & (times <= h2)
df['peak'] = mask.astype(int)
df['peak-off'] = (~mask).astype(int)
print (df)
                       col  peak  peak-off
2015-12-31 23:00:00  23.86     0         1
2016-01-01 00:00:00  22.39     0         1
2016-01-01 01:00:00  20.59     0         1
2016-01-01 02:00:00  16.81     0         1
2016-01-01 03:00:00  17.41     0         1
2016-01-01 04:00:00  17.02     0         1
2016-01-01 05:00:00  15.86     0         1
2016-01-01 06:00:00  15.86     0         1
2016-01-01 07:00:00  15.86     0         1
2016-01-01 08:00:00  15.86     1         0
2016-01-01 09:00:00  15.86     1         0
2016-01-01 10:00:00  15.86     1         0
2016-01-01 18:00:00  15.86     1         0
```

If only hour data solution can be more simple - use [`DatetimeIndex.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.hour.html) for mask:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index) 
print (df.index)
h = df.index.hour
mask = (h >= 8) & (h <= 18)
df['peak'] = mask.astype(int)
df['peak-off'] = (~mask).astype(int)
print (df)
                       col  peak  peak-off
2015-12-31 23:00:00  23.86     0         1
2016-01-01 00:00:00  22.39     0         1
2016-01-01 01:00:00  20.59     0         1
2016-01-01 02:00:00  16.81     0         1
2016-01-01 03:00:00  17.41     0         1
2016-01-01 04:00:00  17.02     0         1
2016-01-01 05:00:00  15.86     0         1
2016-01-01 06:00:00  15.86     0         1
2016-01-01 07:00:00  15.86     0         1
2016-01-01 08:00:00  15.86     1         0
2016-01-01 09:00:00  15.86     1         0
2016-01-01 10:00:00  15.86     1         0
2016-01-01 18:00:00  15.86     1         0
```

Comment: to compute the off_peak column, you could use `df['off_peak'] = -df['peak']+1`